# Why bool tool cuts without creating a face?

Tags: modifiers

I use bool brush to cut the cylinder but the cut leaves empty space instead of leaving a face. Why is that?[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: non-manifold geometry.
I found how to fix this:

1. Install add-on 3D-print toolbox
2. Select your object and press N, select 3D-Print tab
3. In Result section you'll see *Non Manifold Edge*. This informs you about your problems.
4. Go to *Clean up*. Press *Make manifold*